# Safier WinForms Login + Webservice method

Tags: .net, winforms, web-services, encryption

Im trying to create an login to my windows form application so I can filter the users and have a log of the logins etc, if the login is ok it will open the "Main Form".

Im using a webservice, so I send the user/password to the webservice, it authenticate and return if it was suceful or if its failed, everything is working great.

Here is my problem:

People started to use web debuggers to get the server response and then change it, so the login form always get the "User Ok!", then I added encrypted informations using AES encryption, which uses 2 "random keys" to encrypt/decrypt data, but since .NET programs really sucks against decompilers they are getting the method I'm encrypting the data and then creating a fake encrypted response from my server, so cracked again.

Yes, I'm using a code obfuscator, even a paid one, but you know, people always find away to reverse it.

So I need to find a good way to create a system described above, I guess the best way would be like a random encrypt/decrypt way, but not sure if any encryption supports that, I'm creating this question because I've been searching around the internet for a long time and didn't find any good solution for now, and I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: If security matters, think of a distributed application. The private logic can be implemented on the server which is unreachable for not authenticated users. And the thin client application in this situation contain the minimum code necessary to communicate with users.

Comment: How would I decrypt aninformation from the server in my application if the login is implemented on the server? Because somehow I need to send to my application some information like "He is authenticated"

Comment: It sounds like you are creating your own security model vs using an established model. Review the web-services security standard at OASIS and implement this. Using certificates will make it almost impossible for the crackers to send a response from the server.

Comment: OASIS website is kinda messed up, can you tell me exactly what I need to look in there?